# I cannot generate my Hash Key. it says Invalid keytool

Tags: hash, key, keytool

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Angie.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

Comment: Which [tag:keytool] are you using?

Comment: @Eric keytool as in what? I have just copied this code from facebook's website and editted it with the paths according to my system settings

Comment: [tag:keytool] as in the command you are referencing in your question above.  I will take a guess... Are you using this one? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html

Comment: Can you add the link to Facebook's website which you referenced?

Comment: @Eric https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started check this..